# Windows, run shell script from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

Say you have a bash script `test.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Hello World!'
```

In linux if you wanted to run this in Ruby you would just do

```
irb(main):001:0> `./test.sh`
```

In Windows you just get an error

```
Errno::ENOEXEC: Exec format error - ./test.sh
        from (irb):2:in ``'
        from (irb):2
        from c:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Commands work fine

```
irb(main):004:0> `grep`
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

[blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/191120](//blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/191120)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Bash installed, try:

```
irb(main):001:0> `bash ./test.sh`
```